# Migrating from Disqus to facebook comments

Tags: facebook, disqus

we are Migrating from Disqus to Facebook comments on our website "Magazine" Spring mvc.

and we used to get the popular posts based on no. of comments via api call:

> https://disqus.com/api/3.0/threads/listPopular.json?api_key=key&forum=website&interval=7d&limit=10

I tried to read facebook Graph API Reference [Link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/)  but no luck, SO how this can be done via facebook graph api ?

Comment: It can’t; you would have to request the number of comments for _all_ of your URLs, and do the sorting/filtering on your end. And depending on how many of those URLs you actually have, that might quickly turn from a theoretical possibility to a practical impossibility, due to API Rate Limits etc.

Comment: thanks @CBroe , that makes scene.